# Recreating a book layout in memoir

Tags: memoir

I've been investigating book layouts for a project I'm working on and I found the title page and book layout from [the art and practice of printing](https://www.oakknoll.com/pages/books/11519/wm-atkins/art-and-practice-of-printing-a-work-in-six-volumes-the)

I have attempted to create this layout using memoir but to no success.

How would I go about recreating this layout in Memoir?

Comment: Your question will be improved if you show the attempts you mention.

Comment: If I remember correctly rhe 5 volume book contains many chapter examples. Which are you referingf to? If you wanr help you have ro help any helpers. Show whar you have tried. --- GOM